# CRUD com MVC e DAO no PHP

Tags: php, mvc, padrão-dao

Estou começando com programação e estou fazendo um CRUD com MVC e DAO. Gostaria de saber se a forma que estou fazendo está correta, no que podia melhorar e como faço para chamar o metodo de insere do ProdutoController no formulário.

```
<?php

    class Database {

        private $host = "localhost";
        private $username = "root";
        private $password = "123456";
        private $database = "crud";


        public function conecta() 
        {
            $conexao = new mysqli($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->database);
            return $conexao;        
        }
    }
```

---

```
<?php 

    class Produto {

        private $id;
        private $nome;
        private $descricao;
        private $preco;

        public function getId() {
            return $this->id;
        }

        public function setId($id) {
            $this->id = $id;
        }

        public function getNome() {
            return $this->nome;
        }

        public function setNome($nome) {
            $this->nome = $nome;
        }

        public function getDescricao() {
            return $this->descricao;
        }

        public function setDescricao($descricao) {
            $this->descricao = $descricao;
        }

        public function getPreco() {
            return $this->preco;
        }

        public function setPreco($preco) {
            $this->preco = $preco;
        }

    }
```

---

```
<?php  

    class ProdutoDAO {

        function adiciona(Database $conexao, Produto $produto) {

            $query = "INSERT INTO produtos (nome, descricao, preco) VALUES ('{$produto->getNome()}', '{$produto->getDescricao()}', '{$produto->getPreco()}')";  
            mysqli_query($conexao->conecta(), $query);
        }

    }
```

---

```
<?php  

require_once ('../models/Produto.php');
require_once ('../models/ProdutoDAO.php');
require_once ('../config/Database.php');

class ProdutoController {

    public function insere() {
        $nome = $_POST['nome'];
        $descricao = $_POST['descricao'];
        $preco = $_POST['preco'];
        $conexao = new Database();
        $produto = new Produto();
        $produto->setNome($nome);
        $produto->setPreco($preco);
        $produto->setDescricao($descricao);
        $produtoDao = new ProdutoDao();
        $produtoDao->adiciona($conexao, $produto);
    }

}
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="../../public/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Adiciona Produto</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<h3>Adicionar Produto</h3>
<form method="post" action="../../controllers/ProdutoController.php">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Nome</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Descrição</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="descricao">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Preço</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="preco">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Adicionar</button>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Esse código todo fica em um só arquivo ?

Comment: Não. Cada classe tem o seu arquivo. Aonde abro o <? php é um arquivo.

Comment: Editei para separar.

Comment: Marcelo você não está mexendo com MVC puramente neh, é um jeito que você acha que é MVC? (julgo isso porque essa camada de `model` que é a relação com banco) está quase boa, com ajuste melhoria e muito. O que eu não estou entendendo é que você está mexendo com arquivos terminados com `.php` e chamando no navegador? Dê uma explanação!

Comment: Estou começando a ver esse padrões, creio que não deve estar da melhor maneira, por isso queria dicas do q fazer. Não entendi o que quis dizer com chamando no navegador? Tem um formulário que faço o cadastro de um produto, seria isso. Só que não sei como chamar o metodo insere do ProdutoController.php Por isso não tem nenhum php no formulário html.

Comment: Sim Marcelo você está chamando isso no `action:../../controllers/ProdutoController.php`! Nada impede que trabalhe assim, não está errado, não quer dizer que é MVC puramente, mas, você fez a sua própria divisão. Observação nome de arquivos `.php` geralmente colocamos tudo em minusculos.

Comment: Entendi, isso é um detalhe. O meu problema é fazer isso funcionar. Como disse não está perfeito. Como mando os dados do form para o ProdutoController?

Comment: Eu fiz um apanhado no que eu acho que poderia ser melhorado e como utilizar pelo `<form/>`. Como você está usando `mysqli` eu fiz no procedural acho mais simples e fácil entender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu mudaria alguns detalhes:

***classe Database***

```
class Database 
{
    private $host = "localhost";
    private $username = "root";
    private $password = "123456";
    private $database = "crud";
    private $conexao = null; 

    public function __construct()
    {          
        $this->conect();
    }

    public function getConection()
    {
        return $this->conexao;
    }

    private function conect() 
    {
        $this->conexao = mysqli_connect(
                  $this->host, 
                  $this->username, 
                  $this->password, 
                  $this->database);
    }
}
```

---

***class ProdutoDAO***

```
class ProdutoDAO 
{
    private $db;
    public function __construct(Database $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function add(Produto $produto) 
    {
        $nome = $produto->getNome();
        $descricao = $produto->getDescricao();
        $preco = $produto->getPreco();

        $query = "INSERT INTO produtos (nome, descricao, preco) VALUES(?,?,?)"; 
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->db->getConection(), $query);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'sss', $nome, $descricao, $preco);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt); 
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

}
```

Além dessas alterações, acho que a duvida maior seria como executar isso tudo chamando por uma requisição de um `<form />`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="../../public/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Adiciona Produto</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<h3>Adicionar Produto</h3>
<form method="post" action="../../controllers/ProdutoController.php">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Nome</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Descrição</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="descricao">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Preço</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="preco">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Adicionar</button>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

como no seu `<form />` o `action` chama `ProdutoController.php`, crie um arquivo com o mesmo nome e:

```
<?php  

require_once ('../models/Produto.php');
require_once ('../models/ProdutoDAO.php');
require_once ('../config/Database.php');

$db      = new Database();
$dao     = new ProdutoDao($db);

$produto = new Produto();
$produto->setNome($nome);
$produto->setPreco($preco);
$produto->setDescricao($descricao);

$dao->add($produto); // aqui grava o resultado enviado do form

redirect('Location:index.php');
```

Comment: Então, dessa forma que você fez deixando esse arquivo ProdutoController.php como um arquivo normal, sem ser classe e nem ter método funcionou, mas o correto não seria chamar o método insere do ProdutoController.php? Porque dessa forma não teria mais um controller do Produto.

Comment: Então, como disse estou começando na programação e estou tentando fazer um Crud no padrão MVC e DAO. Não sei muita coisa ainda. Sei que o padrão MVC tem o model, view e controller e foi o que estou tentando fazer nessa aplicação. Criei o model (Produto.php), criei o DAO (ProdutoDao.php), criei o controller (ProdutoController.php) e a view que é o formulário de cadastro. Fiz um crud no laravel e tentei reproduzir essa estrutura sem usar ele, mas no Laravel é usado rotas para chamar um método do controller, no meu caso seria o insere do ProdutoController.php.

Comment: Mas se eu quisesse implementar um simples CRUD não poderia usar MVC sem usar um framework ou sem ter que construir um framework para isso? Eu estou fazendo essa aplicação para fins de estudo entende.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48506/discussion-between-marcelo-and-virgilio-novic).

Answer (score 0):

Vamos lá!

Para começar, gostaria de salientar o verdadeiro conceito de MVC:

*MVC é um padrão de arquitetura de software que separa a informação (e as suas regras de negócio) da interface com a qual o usuário interage.*

Ou seja, o seu código de maneira alguma deve ser definido em um bloco gigante como se fosse uma programação estruturada(Como na linguagem C, por exemplo);

É até meio complicado alguém daqui lhe dizer como "chamar" um método...na programação, devemos seguir todos os passos para aprender pensando de forma grande!

Lhe sugiro que dê uma boa olhada no link que enviarei ao fim para aprender todo o passo a passo e se tornar um bom programador no futuro!

Espero sanar outras dúvidas suas no futuro! ;)

https://www.webdevbr.com.br/mvc-e-php-entendendo-o-padrao-na-pratica-criando-um-framework-php

Comment: Não entendi o que quis dizer com bloco gigante. São arquivos separados e não um unico arquivo.

Comment: Editei e separei os arquivos pq não é um unico arquivo na minha aplicação e sim arquivos separados. Tem o nome da classe e a tag de abertura do php então pensei q o pessoal ia sacar.

Comment: Melhorou um pouco! Cara, existem vários frameworks que você poderia utilizar para ajudar no desenvolvimento...essa pergunta que você fez, inclusive já existe no próprio stackoverflow...mas no ".com";

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17425765/php-mvc-call-controller-function-from-view

Comment: Sim, fiz alguma coisa no Laravel e sei que através de rotas eu chamo o método. Mas gostaria de fazer esse crud no php puro, sem framework.