# Manipulação de Dados Entre Camadas MVC

Tags: php, jquery, mvc

Bom dia pessoal.

Tenho uma dúvida/Problema.

Estou usando *php* e *javaScript/Jquery* com o padrão de projetos *MVC* e *DAO*. Quero saber como faço para pegar os dados do banco de dados que estão no *DAO* usando *AJAX* e enviar para *VIEW*. Porém, esses dados devem ser enviados para o *control* para então pegar esses dados e enviar para a *VIEW*.

Alguém pode fazer um exemplo simples?

Comment: É muito amplo, deve pesquisar mais sobre esses detalhes. Já foi abordado sobre esse assunto nesse link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/165442/crud-com-mvc-e-dao-no-php

Comment: Possível duplicata de [CRUD com MVC e DAO no PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/165442/crud-com-mvc-e-dao-no-php)