# PHP com DAO + mysqli

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, mysqli, padrão-dao, procedural

DAO precisa, necessariamente, ser uma classe? Ou eu poderia criar métodos dentro de um arquivo .php sem o encapsulamento de uma classe?

Se não é possível, qual o nome do DAO sem classe (nome de algum padrão igual ou semelhante)?

É aconselhável usar DAO (com ou sem classe) com mysqli procedural? Por que? Quais as vantagens e desvantagens?

Comment: É questão de estilo, já tentou usar os dois para ver qual parece melhor?

Comment: Pelo que ando lendo, você usar objeto (classe) é quase que praticamente organização. Então você ter todos seus métodos em um arquivo separado, ou até em um único, creio eu que não teria problemas, pensando como exemplo o "phpmyadmin". Tomara que o pessoal conhecedor responda.

Comment: Boa maneira de resolver uma pergunta de um teste :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***"DAO precisa, necessariamente, ser uma classe? Ou eu poderia criar métodos dentro de um arquivo .php sem o encapsulamento de uma classe?"***

Não existe DAO sem classes. Isso não significa que você não possa fazer algo parecido, mas não será DAO. O DAO tem responsabilidades bem específicas:

- provê uma interface que abstrai o acesso a dados;
- lê e grava a partir da origem de dados (banco de dados, arquivo,
  memória, etc.); e
- **encapsula o acesso aos dados, de forma que as demais classes não
  precisam saber sobre isso.**

E isso fica mais evidente na **[documentação da Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dataaccessobject-138824.html)**. Que diz isso:

> Use um Data Access Object (DAO) para abstrair e encapsular todo o
>   acesso à fonte de dados. O DAO gerencia a conexão com a fonte de dados
>   para obter e armazenar dados.

Você não irá conseguir realizar essas responsabilidades sem classes.

Você precisa se perguntar:

- Nessa minha aplicação eu tenho várias entidades que serão relacionadas entre si? Ou cada entidade será tratada unilateralmente.
- O QUANTO essa aplicação pode crescer?
- Quantas tabelas eu vou acessar ao mesmo tempo?
- Quantos bancos eu vou acessar?
- E se alterar o banco ou o servidor?

---

Ao invés de pensar em usar o DAO, você pode criar um CRUD genérico.

**UM EXEMPLO:**

Vamos supor que toda a sua aplicação estará estruturada, ou seja, sem instancias de objeto e cada arquivo(script) será executado um por vez quando for chamado pelo cliente e essa aplicação não irá crescer pois ela é bem simples....

Um hotsite.

**crud.php**

```
function inserir($tabela, $values = array()){

    $con = conexao();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$tabela;
    $valoresDB = "(";
    $valoresBlind = "("
    foreach($values as $key => $valor){
        $valoresDB .= $key.","
        $valoresBlind .= "?,"
    }
    $sql .= " ".substr($valoresDB, 0, -1).") ".substr($valoresBlind, 0, -1).") ";
    $stm = mysqli_stmt_prepare($con, $sql);
    foreach($values as $valor){
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stm, "s", $valor); 
    }
    if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stm)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function alterar($tabela, $values = array(), $where = array()){
    // altera um registro
}

function deletar($tabela, $id, $where){
    // deletar
}

function listar($tabela, $id, $where){
    // listar 1 ou mais registros
}
```

Neste caso, esse CRUD poderia atender melhor que um DAO, pois você escreveria menos códigos, facilitaria sua manutenção, desenvolvimento, etc.

---

***Se não é possível, qual o nome do DAO sem classe (nome de algum padrão igual ou semelhante)?***

CRUD. =D

Não existe um padrão específico de CRUD para programação estruturada.

"Se não é possível"...

Na minha opinião É POSSÍVEL você fazer algo parecido com o DAO. Você pode criar arquivos com o nome `ProdutoDAO.php` e criar funções em CRUD. Mas isso não será DAO.

Também é importante conhecer vários tipos de padrões, ou até criar o seu. Porque não?

**Segundo as características de [Padrão de Projeto](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padr%C3%A3o_de_projeto_de_software#Caracter%C3%ADsticas_de_um_padr%C3%A3o_de_projeto)**

1. Devem possuir um NOME, que descreva o problema, as soluções e
   conseqüências. Um nome permite definir o vocabulário a ser utilizado
   pelos projetistas e desenvolvedores em um nível mais alto de
   abstração.
2. Todo padrão deve relatar de maneira clara a qual (is) PROBLEMA(s)
   ele deve ser aplicado, ou seja, quais são os problemas que quando
   inserido em um determinado contexto o padrão conseguirá
   resolve-lo.Alguns podendo exigir pré-condições.
3. Solução descreve os elementos que compõem o projeto, seus
   relacionamentos, responsabilidades e colaborações. Um padrão deve
   ser uma SOLUÇÃO concreta, ele deve ser exprimido em forma de
   gabarito (algoritmo) que, no entanto pode ser aplicado de maneiras
   diferentes.
4. Todo padrão deve relatar quais são as suas CONSEQUÊNCIAS para que
   possa ser analisada a solução alternativa de projetos e para a
   compreensão dos benefícios da aplicação do projeto.

---

**É aconselhável usar DAO (com ou sem classe) com mysqli procedural? Por que? Quais as vantagens e desvantagens?**

O mysqli procedural ou orientado a objeto vai depender de você. Ao meu ver o php manteve a linha procedural para que os "old schools" não sentissem tanto a diferença e/ou para facilitar a manutenção de aplicações antigas. Vejo isso pelo próprio **[manual](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php)** que diz assim:

> Usuários migrando da antiga extensão mysql podem preferir a interface
>   procedural. A interface procedural é semelhante à da antiga extensão
>   mysql. Em muitos casos, os nomes das funções diferem apenas pelo
>   prefixo. Algumas funções mysqli tomam um identificador de conexão como
>   seu primeiro argumento, enquanto as funções correspondentes na antiga
>   interface mysql o tomam como um último argumento opcional.

Tradução livre =p

Usar mysqli de forma procedural ou orientada a objeto não muda nada. Se houver algum ganho em performance ela não é relevante. Talvez a única diferença é que com OOP você consegue algo assim:

```
class Banco extends mysqli{..}
```

Faça da forma que for mais confortável para você.

**EDIT**

Depois de pesquisar um pouco, não encontrei desvantagens ou vantagens em usar o mysqli na forma procedural ou OO. Talvez seja mais relevante saber se você deva usar prepared statements ou não para o ganho de performance. Tem uma **[publicação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/47440/15361)** do @Maniero sobre isso. Inclusive achei interessante destacar:

> Além disto é possível ter algum ganho de performance porque ele (*prepared statements*) pode
>   ser compilado e cacheado. Mas dependendo do padrão de uso não será
>   diferente de uma consulta não preparada. Em outros casos este possível
>   ganho nem será aproveitado. Lembre-se que a preparação dura apenas
>   durante a sessão que costuma ser curta.

Ou seja, até nesta questão, isso não é TAO relevante e me parece que não está consagrada. Eu lí poucos artigos, não muito importantes, que defendem o uso do mysqli OO. Uns dizem que o PHP está cada vez mais se "Orientando a Objeto" e que o quanto antes você se acostumar a programar assim, melhor, pois "*vai que o php deprecia a forma procedural*"...

É mais fácil consultar a "mãe dináh"!

Mas essas questões não estão relacionadas diretamente com o DAO. Você pode usar qualquer forma de acesso ao banco desde que você faça uso do padrão DAO para abstrair e encapsular todos os acessos ao data source, extrair e/ou armazenar informações, etc.

**[Um exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/165457/15361)** do uso de DAO com mysqli procedural do @VirgilioNovic

Também achei interessante a **[resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/113866/15361)** do @utluiz sobre DAO, está bem completa, vale a pena dar uma olhada.

Comment: Obrigado ajudou bastante, só não aceito a resposta porque queria saber mais sobre se é aconselhável, as vantagens e desvantagens de usar DAO + mysqli procedural

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam realmente eu não sei aconselhar isso para uso específico em DAO. Mas na minha visão isso não muda em termo de performance. A diferença pode estar em poder estender o mysqli e usa-lo orientado a objeto. A mesma coisa você consegue fazer com o PDO. ACHO (não tenho certeza) que é mais uma questão de gosto mesmo.

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam mas mesmo assim. Espera vir outras respostas. Pode ser até que eu não esteja totalmente certo, visto que não houve muita aceitação.